# Can Saving Shield and Bodyguard stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

The two feats [Saving Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/saving-shield-combat) And [Bodyguard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/bodyguard-combat) allow you to grant bonuses to adjacent allies who are being attacked. If a character with both feats is defending an adjacent ally would both feats apply? One uses an immediate action and the other uses An attack of opportunity action.

Comment: Just note that saving shield would not stack with any shield bonus the ally already has.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, because their bonus types stack and they use compatible actions.**

At the expense of an immediate action and an AoO, you can grant your Ally +4 to his AC for one attack. Note that Saving Shield will last for the entire attack or full attack, Bodyguard only for one attack, though you can use it multiple times a round.

---

[Saving shield](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/advancedFeats.html#saving-shield) grants a +2 **shield** bonus, which does not stack with any other shield bonuses your ally might have.

[Aid Another](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#aid-another) grants

> [...] a +2 bonus to AC against that opponent's next attack [...]

Since no type is specified, it is an **untyped** bonus. These generally stack with all other bonus types.

Comment: Just keep in mind that for Bodyguard to work, the enemy must be in your threatened area, and the ally must be adjacent to you. If you are using a weapon without reach (or dont have reach yourself), both of them must be adjacent to you. I dont see a note of duration on saving shield, and nothing on the wording seems to indicate that it should last for more than one attack, so, since it requires an Immediate Action, i dont think you can use Saving Shield to grant +2 to AC against a full attack, it should work only on one attack, as you only have one Immediate Action per round.

Answer (score 7):

You can use one or both or none, depending on action economy, location of opponent, and your current status/condition.

If the opponent who is attacking is outside your threatened range, you can not use Aid Another, thus Bodyguard is not usable.

If you are flat-footed, unless you have an additional feat such as Combat Reflexes* or a class feature like Uncanny Dodge, you can not do either.

Otherwise the shield bonus and untyped bonus will stack giving a +4 to your ally's AC.

*Edit:The Bodyguard feat has Combat Reflexes as a pre-req, so of course you will have it.

Comment: The ruling here on the bodyguard feat is wrong. As of now there is no official ruling on the feat, however [the author, Jason Nelson, posted this](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2phpj?Bodyguard-Forum-Compilation-and-Clarification#15).

Comment: *Also a Ranger with the Guardian Combat Style could get Bodyguard without Combat Reflexes.